# Is there any difference between Mantra-Brahmin and other kinds of Brahmin?

Tags: shiva, puranas, mantras, shiva-purana

The following is from Shiva Purana's Vidyeśvara-saṃhitā (Chapter 17). It is about how Kshatriyas, Vaishyas and Shudras can become Brahmins.

> क्षत्रियः पञ्चलक्षण क्षत्रत्वमपनेष्यति । पुनश्च पञ्चलक्षण क्षत्रियो **ब्राह्मणो** भवेत् ।। मन्त्रसिद्धिर्जपाद्यैव क्रमान्मुक्तो भवेन्नर । वैश्यस्तु पञ्चलक्षण वैश्यत्वमपनेष्यति ।। पुनश्च पञ्चलक्षण मन्त्रक्षत्रिय उच्यते । पुनश्च पञ्चलक्षण क्षत्रत्वमपनेष्यति ।। पुनश्च पञ्चलक्षण **मन्त्रब्राह्मण** उच्यते । शूद्रश्चैव नमोऽन्तेन पञ्चविंशतिलक्षत ।। मन्त्रविप्रत्वमापद्य पश्चाच्छुद्रो भवेद्द्विज । नारीवाथ नरो वाथ ब्राह्मणो वान्य एव वा ।।

So it says Kshatriyas become Brahmins, and Vaishyas/Shudras become Mantra-Brahmins. According to another translation given on [Hindu Scriptures website](https://www.hinduscriptures.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/30F_Chapter_24_3.pdf) it is written here that

> In case a Sudra adding Namah at the end of the mantra, recites the mantra by twenty five lacs of times, then he achieves the position of a mantra Brahmana. **After reciting the japam by twenty five lacs of times again, a Sudra is turned into a pure Brahmana.**

Is this quoted part in bold part explicitly stated, or is it implied from the previous verses? **Is there any place where it says mantra-Brahmin is not a pure-Brahmin or is it translator's own opinion?**

Answer (score 0):

No. On further reading it says that the person has **lost all the qualities of his previous varna. So he has nothing to do with his previous varna.**

> (124) A Kṣatriya must repeat the mantra five hundred thousand times to remove Kṣatratva.
>
> (125) A Vaiśya dispels the Vaiśyatva by five hundred thousand japas.
>
> (126) Then he becomes a mantra-Kṣatriya by repeating it five hundred thousand times. He then dispels the Kṣatratva by five hundred thousand japas.

Not only this, verse 124 also says that Kshatriya becomes **only Brahmin, it does not say mantra-Brahmin:**

> (124) A further repetition of five hundred thousand times enables him to become a brahmin.

So "mantra-brahmin" is **only a a way of specifying how person becomes brahmin, ie, using mantras.** It is a type of Brahmin that has lost all qualities of previous caste and is now only in Brahmin varna.